# How to pass (properly) a Java Object from a Servlet to a JSP page

Tags: hibernate, jsp, orm, servlets

I've been everywhere on the web, and i'm little lost and couldn't solve my problem.

I'm creating a web application using Eclipse, with JSP on the client side, and Servet/Hibernate on the server side.
I'm trying to pass an Object to a JSP page form a servlet.

In the servlet :

```
Contact c = dao.getContact(dataID);

request.setAttribute("data", c);

getServletContext()
    .getRequestDispatcher("/"+url+"?id="+dataID).forward(request, response);
```

In the JSP page :

```
Contact contact = (Contact)request.getAttribute("data");
```

Contact is an ORM, which has attributes like "lastname".

But i'm getting this error message :

```
GRAVE: "Servlet.service()" pour la servlet GetData a généré une exception
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext configured!
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:683)
    at domain.DAOContact.getContact(DAOContact.java:39)
    at domain.GetData.doGet(GetData.java:27)
```

So I tried to figure out why, and somewhere I read that I need to set the current session context to "thread" in the hibernate config file. But when I did this, i get this message :

```
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [GetData] in context with path [/CarnetContacts] threw exception [org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session] with root cause
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:215)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:190)
    at domain.Contact_$$_javassist_1.getLastName(Contact_$$_javassist_1.java)
```

The second line of the message indicates it has to do with lazy loading, but the last line i shows that the bug occurs when the program is trying to get the "lastname" attribute, which is basically a string, so I don't think it's "lazy loaded".

So if somebody could help me find a solution, that would be very kind.

Code of the dao method :

```
    public Contact getContact(int contactId){
        Session session = HibernateSessionFactory.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
        t.begin();
        Contact contact =(Contact) session.load(Contact.class, new Integer(contactId));
        t.commit();
        return contact; 
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your specific problem in this case is that you use `Session.load()` instead of `Session.get()`.

`load()` returns a lazily-initialized proxy, therefore it should be used only in special cases, in the most cases you need to use `get()`.

Generally speaking, besides this particular case, problem with lazy initialization in view layer can be solved using one of the following approaches:

- Use [Open Session in View pattern](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessioninView)
- Fetch all required data before rendering the view (using `JOIN FETCH`, `Hibernate.initialize()`, etc)